# algorithm, how to start line numbering at given number (using algorithm2e)

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I wonder how to start a code at a specific number; this is necessary when the algorithm is broken over two pages.

A small example that I would like to start at line 39 instead of line 1. Is there a way to do it?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,toc=bibliography,nonchapterprefix,parskip=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}
  \SetKwData{Left}{left}
  \SetKwData{Up}{up}
  \SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

 \Indm
 \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
 \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
\Indp
\BlankLine
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\; }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1em}
```

best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `algorithm2e` package has a `noresetcount` option, but this has the effect of numbering all algorithms continuously.

You can define a `\rememberlines` macro that will store the line number that was current at the end of an `algorithm` environment and a `\resumenumbering` macro that uses that value.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,toc=bibliography,parskip=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\rememberlines}{\xdef\rememberedlines{\number\value{AlgoLine}}}
\newcommand{\resumenumbering}{\setcounter{AlgoLine}{\rememberedlines}}

\begin{document}

\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}
  \SetKwData{Left}{left}
  \SetKwData{Up}{up}
  \SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

  \Indm
  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
  \Indp
  \BlankLine
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}}
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}
  }
\rememberlines
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\resumenumbering
  \SetKwData{Left}{left}
  \SetKwData{Up}{up}
  \SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

  \Indm
  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
  \Indp
  \BlankLine
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}}
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]